# How to Print Out A Split Array using GUI

Tags: arrays, user-interface, split

Hi I'm having a hard time printing out my split array in the window , I'm trying to print them out by user's split size but the output in the windows print them out one by one. This my code with GUI

```
        String []in_array;

        in_array = letters.split("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= in_array.length; i++) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, in_array[i-1]);         

         if (i % sizeSplit == 0) {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");

              }

            }
        }

    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Given input is not divisible by input size");
    }   
}
```

I am trying to convert this code to GUI but like I said the output is different instead showing my split strings given by the user's split size, the output/window print them one by one

```
            System.out.println("Enter String:");
    String letters = lagoScan.next();

    final int numInLetters = letters.length(); // converted string to number length

System.out.println("Enter Split Size:");
    int splitSize = lagoScan.nextInt();

    if (numInLetters % splitSize == 0) {

    System.out.println("The Given String is: "+letters);
    System.out.println("The Split String are:");


    String []in_array;

    in_array = letters.split(""); //Note this there is no delimiter 
    for (int i = 1; i <= in_array.length; i++) {

          System.out.print(in_array[i - 1]);


          if (i % splitSize == 0) {
           System.out.println();
          }

        }

    }

    else {
    System.out.println("Given input is not divisible by input size.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your split array parts to a new string and display that in a `JOptionPane` after you finish parsing.

```
String textToDisplay = "";
textToDisplay = textToDisplay + splitPart1 + '\n';
textToDisplay = textToDisplay + splitPart2 + '\n';  
...  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textToDisplay);
```

Comment: Okay however it will change my user's split size if I split it manually. To put it simply how can I display split strings in joptionpane?